# Python - doing maths with a nested list

Tags: python

If I have a nested list, e.g. `x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]`, how can I calculate the difference between all of them? Let's called the lists inside `x - A, B, and C`. I want to calculate the difference of A from B & C, then B from A & C, then C from A & B, then put them in a list diff = [].
**My problem is correctly indexing the numbers and using them to do maths with corresponding elements in other lists.**
This is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
diff = [] 
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]!=x[j]:
            a = x[i]
            b = x[j]
            for h in range(len(a)):
                d = a[h] - b[h]
                diff.append(d)
```

Essentially for the difference of A to B it is `([1-2] + [2-4] + [3-6])`
I would like it to return: `diff = [[diff(A,B), diff(A,C)], [diff(B,A), diff(B,C)], [diff(C,A), diff(C,B)]]` with the correct differences between points.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use numpy for this. For example: `import numpy as np; np.array([1,2,3]) - np.array([2,4,6])`

Comment: So, `diff([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6])` is `1-2 + 2-4 + 3-6` rather than `[1-2, 2-4, 3-6]`? What does `diff(A,B)` actually represent in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is actually not that far off. As Aniketh mentioned, one issue is your use of `x[i] != x[j]`. Since `x[i]` and `x[j]` are arrays, that will actually *always* evaluate to false.

The reason is that python will not do a useful comparison of arrays by default. It will just check if the array *reference* is the same. This is obviously not what you want, you are trying to see if the array is at the same index in `x`. For that use `i !=j`.

Though there are other solutions posted here, I'll add mine below because I already wrote it. It makes use of python's list comprehensions.

```py
def pairwise_diff(x):
    diff = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        A = x[i]
        for j in range(len(x)):
            if i != j:
                B = x[j]
                assert len(A) == len(B)
                item_diff = [A[i] - B[i] for i in range(len(A))]
                diff.append(sum(item_diff))

    # Take the answers and group them into arrays of length 2
    return [diff[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, len(diff), 2)]


x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]
print(pairwise_diff(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those problems where it's really helpful to know a bit of Python's standard library — especially [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).

For example to get the pairs of lists you want to operate on, you can reach for [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]
list(permutations(x, r=2))
```

This gives the pairs of lists your want:

```
[([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7]),
 ([2, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]),
 ([3, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6])]
```

Now, if you could just group those by the first of each pair...[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does just this.

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]
list(list(g) for k, g in groupby(permutations(x, r=2), key=lambda p: p[0]))
```

Which produces a list of lists grouped by the first:

```
[[([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]), ([1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7])],
 [([2, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]), ([2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7])],
 [([3, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3]), ([3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6])]]
```

Putting it all together, you can make a simple function that subtracts the lists the way you want and pass each pair in:

```
from itertools import permutations, groupby

def sum_diff(pairs):
    return [sum(p - q for p, q in zip(*pair)) for pair in pairs]
    
x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]

# call sum_diff for each group of pairs
result = [sum_diff(g) for k, g in groupby(permutations(x, r=2), key=lambda p: p[0])]

# [[-6, -9], [6, -3], [9, 3]]
```

This reduces the problem to just a couple lines of code and will be performant on large lists. And, since you mentioned the difficulty in keeping indices straight, notice that this uses *no* indices in the code other than selecting the first element for grouping.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was working on. Kudos on getting there first and doing a better job of explaining it that I probably would have!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I believe you're looking for. I will explain it below:

```
def diff(a, b):
  total = 0
  for i in range(len(a)):
    total += a[i] - b[i]
  return total

x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]
  
differences = []
for i in range(len(x)):
  soloDiff = []
  for j in range(len(x)):
    if i != j:
      soloDiff.append(diff(x[i],x[j]))
  differences.append(soloDiff)

print(differences)
```

Output:

```
[[-6, -9], [6, -3], [9, 3]]
```

First off, in your explanation of your algorithm, you are making it very clear that you should use a function to calculate the differences between two lists since you will be using it repeatedly.

Your for loops start off fine, but you should have a second list to append `diff` to 3 times. Also, when you are checking for repeats you need to make sure that `i != j`, not `x[i] != x[j]`

Let me know if you have any other questions!!

Answer (score 1):

this is the simplest solution i can think:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]
x = np.array(x)
vectors = ['A','B','C']
for j in range(3):
    for k in range(3):
        if j!=k:
            print(vectors[j],'-',vectors[k],'=', x[j]-x[k])
```

which will return

```
A - B = [-1 -2 -3]
A - C = [-2 -3 -4]
B - A = [1 2 3]
B - C = [-1 -1 -1]
C - A = [2 3 4]
C - B = [1 1 1]
```